# Unable to paste unicode character into MySQL console

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am working on a server Ubuntu 16.04 in which is installed MySQL 5.7.31.

I have a trouble about paste a unicode character like ù or à in the console of MySQL.

What kind of check I can do to solve this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check that you're using UTF-8 (`utf8mb4` ideally) as your character set for the connection, the server, the database, the table, the columns and so on. *Everything* needs to be set the same.

Comment: Hi @tadman. Thanks for your response. I have checked all character set and the settings are all utf8. I haven't problem to display a special character, instead I have problem to digit a special character in the MySQL console.

Comment: If it doesn't work then something is *still* not right. Are you sure the character you're pasting is UTF-8 and not Windows-1252 or something?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, but I don't understand. This post is not related about the visualization of a special character. Instead, it is related to the fact that I have a query (a string) with a special character and if I copy and paste this query the special character is not preserved when I paste the query in the MySQL console.

Comment: For example, if I copy a query like this **insert into table_A values ('Testà')** in MySQL console the special character is not preserved and the query became **insert into table_A values ('Test')** without the last character.

Comment: What console? What character set is your console set to use?

Comment: Hi @tadman. Due to the fact that this post has been marked as duplicate (but is not a duplicate) I have opened this new post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574540/mysql-default-character-set-option). I have found that the problem is related to a directive in the [client] and [mysql] sections.