# MySQL default-character-set option

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

In a server Ubuntu 16.04 I have installed MySQL 5.7.31.

To setup UTF8 in MySQL, I have changed the following sections.

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = false #force encoding to uft8
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Running the instruction

```
show global variables like '%char%'"
```

I can see that MySQL appears to be well configured.

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

And also running the instruction

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';

+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

However, when I enter into the default console of MySQL

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I cannot digit the special characters (like ù or à).

After many investigation, I have found that if I comment out the part for UTF8 in [client] and [mysql] configurations then I can re-digit the special characters.

Why have I this behavior?

Can I safety remove the configurations about UTF8 from the sections [client] and [mysql]?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try using `utf8mb4` as a default so you can capture not just accents, but the full range of UTF-8 characters.  It's worth checking the encoding of your system, and verifying the insertion after with `HEX()`. For example, `é` should encode as `C3A9`. If it comes out as something else it's possible to work backwards and figure out why.

Comment: Hi @tadman. Thanks for your reply. Changing the default character (yes, I know that I can use this encoding to be fully utf8) seems to not work for my problem. I am constantly unable to input (digit) a special character. Only after I comment the directives in the two section ([client] and [mysql]), then I am able to input (or digit again) a special character. It is a very strange behavior.